# kendo Grid design is not proper after excel export

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here i have posted Html code and JQuery code given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                toolbar: ["excel"],
                excel: {
                    fileName: "CheckInCheckOut_<%=DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")%>.xlsx",
                    proxyURL: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/TestURL.aspx") %>",
                    filterable: true
                },
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                actions: { type: "string" },
                                LastName: { type: "string" },
                                FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                Gender: { type: "string" },
                                CabinNumber: { type: "string" },
                                AgeGroup: { type: "string" },
                                PickupPassword: { type: "string" },
                                PrimaryGuestFolioID: { type: "string" },
                                PrimaryGuestFirstName: { type: "string" },
                                PrimaryGuestLastName: { type: "string" },
                                PrimaryGuestRelation: { type: "string" },
                                PrimaryGuestCabinNumber: { type: "string" },
                                PUP1FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP1LastName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP1Relation: { type: "string" },
                                PUP2FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP2LastName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP2Relation: { type: "string" },
                                PUP3FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP3LastName: { type: "string" },
                                PUP3Relation: { type: "string" },
                                DropOffMethod:{ type: "string" },
                                CheckinDate: { type: "string" },
                                CheckinTime: { type: "string" },
                                HandyPhone: { type: "string" },
                                PickUpMethod: { type: "string" },
                                DropOffSignature: { type: "string" },
                                DropOffConcierge: { type: "string" },
                                CheckoutDate: { type: "string" },
                                CheckoutTime: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                filterable: {
                    mode: "row"
                }
            });
            var exportFlag = false;
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport", function (e) {
                if (!exportFlag) {
                    e.sender.hideColumn(0);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    exportFlag = true;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                    });
                } else {
                    e.sender.showColumn(0);
                    exportFlag = false;
                }
            });
            $("span.k-filtercell[data-field='DropOffSignature']").hide();//do not allow search on signature field
        });
    </script>


<div class="bluetbl noscrolltbl" style="float:left; width:3345px">
        <asp:Repeater ID="RPTCheckInCheckOutDetails" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="grid">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col class="reportguestname" />
                        <col style="width: 60px" /><!--Last Name-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" /><!--First Name-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" /><!--Gender-->
                        <col style="width: 60px" /><!--Cabin Number-->
                        <col style="width: 65px" /><!--Age Group-->
                        <col style="width: 45px" /><!--Youth Program-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" /><!--PRimary First name-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 37px" /><!--primary Relations-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" />  
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 37px" /><!--PUP1 Relations-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 37px" /> <!--PUP2 Relations-->
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 50px" />
                        <col style="width: 37px" /> <!--PUP3 Relations-->
                        <col style="width: 47px" /><!-- Drop Off Method -->
                        <col style="width: 47px" />
                        <col style="width: 45px" />
                        <col style="width: 48px" /><!--DO Iconceirge-->
                        <col style="width: 44px" />
                        <col style="width: 44px" />
                        <col style="width: 90px" />
                        <col style="width: 40px" /><!-- Pick Up Method -->
                        <col style="width: 40px" />
                        <col style="width: 40px" />
                        <col style="width: 40px" />
                        <col style="width: 40px" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="actions">Actions</th>
                            <th data-field="LastName">Last Name</th>
                            <th data-field="FirstName">First Name</th>
                            <th data-field="Gender">Gender</th>
                            <th data-field="CabinNumber">Cabin Number</th>
                            <th data-field="AgeGroup">Age Group</th>
                            <th data-field="YouthProgram">Youth Program</th>
                            <th data-field="PrimaryGuestFirstName">Primary First Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PrimaryGuestlastName">Primary Last Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PrimaryGuestRelation">Primary Relation</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP1FirstName">PUP1 First Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP1LastName">PUP1 Last Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP1Relation">PUP1 Relation</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP2FirstName">PUP2 First Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP2LastName">PUP2 Last Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP2Relation">PUP2 Relation</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP3FirstName">PUP3 First Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP3LastName">PUP3 Last Name</th>
                            <th data-field="PUP3Relation">PUP3 Relation</th>
                            <th data-field="DropOffMethod">Drop Off Method</th>
                            <th data-field="HandyPhone">Handyphone</th>
                            <th data-field="DroppedOffBy">Dropped Off By</th>
                            <th data-field="DropOffConcierge">Drop off IConcierge #</th>
                            <th data-field="CheckinDate">Drop Off Date</th>
                            <th data-field="CheckinTime">Drop Off Time</th>                            
                            <th data-field="DropOffSignature">Drop Off Signature</th>
                            <th data-field="PickUpMethod">Pick Up Method</th>
                            <th data-field="PickUpBy">Pick Up By</th>
                            <th data-field="CheckoutDate">Pick Up Date</th>
                            <th data-field="CheckoutTime">Pick Up Time</th>
                            <th data-field="PickUpStaff">Pick Up Staff</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut!=null ? this.GetCSRReprintLink(((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.ID) : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.FullName.Last : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.FullName.First : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.Gender.ToString().Substring(0,1) : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.CabinNumber : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.AgeGroup!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.AgeGroup.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.AgeGroup!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.AgeGroup.YouthProgarm!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).Reservation.ChildGuest.AgeGroup.YouthProgarm.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.FullName.First : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.FullName.Last : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails!=null &&  ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.Relation!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).RegistrationDetails.PrimaryGuest.Relation.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 1 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].FullName.First : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 1 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].FullName.Last : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 1 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].Relation != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[0].Relation.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 2 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].FullName.First : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 2 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].FullName.Last : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count >= 2 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].Relation != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[1].Relation.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count == 3 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].FullName.First : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count == 3 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].FullName != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].FullName.Last : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs.Count == 3 && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].Relation != null  ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).PUPs[2].Relation.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn !=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Method.ToString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Device !=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Device.Name : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Guest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Guest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Guest.FullName.ToString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Guest!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Guest.IConciergeNumber : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.ActivityTime.Date.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.ActivityTime.ToString("hh:mm tt") : string.Empty%></td>                    
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Signature!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Signature.Length > 0 ? "<img style='width:142px;' src='data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.Signature) + "' />" : ""%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.Method.ToString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.Guest!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.Guest.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.Guest.FullName.ToString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut !=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.ActivityTime.Date.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.ActivityTime.ToString("hh:mm tt") : string.Empty%></td>
                    <td><%# ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.InsertedBy!=null && ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.InsertedBy.FullName!=null ? ((GPNS.BusinessLayer.ReportManager.ReservationData)Container.DataItem).CheckIn.CheckOut.InsertedBy.FullName.ToShortString() : string.Empty%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

I have used above code for kendo grid, when i export the data into excel, i was trying to hide a column. In that case column was hide but the kendo grid design is not proper after export.